# Dcom Error running a SQL Package

Tags: sql-server, ssis, ssis-2014

This is the first time I have come across this type of error.  I am running a process task and it runs fine until I add it to the scheduler (sql agent).

> Date       3/2/2017 4:13:05 PM
> Log        Windows NT (System)
>
> Source     Microsoft-Windows-DistributedCOM
> Category        (0)
> Event       10016
> User        NT SERVICE\SQLSERVERAGENT
> Computer        CFBF-SQL2

Message

> The application-specific permission settings do not grant Local Activation permission for the COM Server application with CLSID
> {806835AE-FD04-4870-A1E8-D65535358293}
> and APPID
> {EE4171E6-C37E-4D04-AF4C-8617BC7D4914}
> to the user NT SERVICE\SQLSERVERAGENT SID (S-1-5-80-344959196-2060754871-2302487193-2804545603-1466107430) from address LocalHost (Using LRPC) running in the application container Unavailable SID (Unavailable). This security permission can be modified using the Component Services administrative tool.